# Logic / Algorithm for Server Monitoring and Notification

Tags: algorithm, wmi, logic, monitoring

I am currently developing a small server monitoring application that uses WMI to collect hardware information such as CPU and RAM usage, as well as some other methods to query services (FTP, HTTP, IMAP, SMTP, Raw TCP Socket, etc).

I already created the data collectors for each of the items above, and able to obtain data from them. The services data provider will provide the response time and the server response of the service each time the service monitor is refresh.

However I hit a wall then trying to construct the logic for notifying the users of errors and recoveries. My Services class, which the the base class for all of the services subclasses contains several events - OnRefreshed, OnErrorOccured, OnErrorRecovered, OnResponseTimeThresholdReached, OnResponseTimeThresholdRecovered.

I am trying to achieve the following scenario:

- When the services are responding normally, the OnRefreshed event is fired on each of the refresh intervals.
- When an error occured (e.g. 404 on HTTP), the OnErrorOccured event is to be fired, and if the user desires to have a notification sent, proceed with sending the notification, but only once, until the service recovers.
- When a service recovered from an error, the OnErrorRecovered event is to be fired, and if the user desires notification, send it only once, until there is an error again.
- Same thing goes to the ResponseTime events, which should be fired when the corresponding situation occured.
- If a service alternates between OK and Error / ThresholdReached on each refresh intervals, there should be a cool down time between the notifications, to prevent notification spree.

I am currently building this application using C#. Any enlightenment on this issue, or any other better solutions to implement this is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am no C# coder, but here is what I would do for each service. 
I assume that you would be storing the notification information for each service somewhere. 
I would maintain a notification array for each service with < user > -> flag mapping.  The flags are 
0 - not notified 
1 - error_occurred_notified 
2 - error_recovered_notified 
3 - both

1. Whenever a user is notified of an event, mark it based on the flag
2. Whenever refresh event happens, set the flag to 0.